# Java - Multi threading sound clips to play at same time

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

Problem;  Only hearing one sound clip when executed.  After one sound has played the other doesn't play & neither can play at the same time.

Result;  To be able to play 2 sounds at the same time.

Code:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.sound.sampled.*;
 public class ThreadPlay extends Thread {
 private String filename; // The name of the file to play
 private boolean finished; // A flag showing that the thread has finished

private ThreadPlay(String fname) {
    filename = fname;
    finished = false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPlay s1 = new ThreadPlay("soundClip1.wav");
    ThreadPlay s2 = new ThreadPlay("soundClip2.wav");
    s1.start();
    s2.start();

    while (!s1.finished || !s2.finished);


    System.exit(0); // Java Sound bug fix...
}

public void run() {

    try {
        File file = new File(filename);
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        while (clip.isRunning()) { Thread.sleep(100); }
        clip.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) { }
    finished = true;
}
  }
```

Audio Lines:

```
 AudioSystem.getMixerInfo() results in:
                  [Ljavax.sound.sampled.Mixer$Info;@52cc8049

 Array length: 7 
 Contents:
     PulseAudio Mixer, version 0.02
     default [default], version 4.4.0-66-generic
     PCH [plughw:0,0], version 4.4.0-66-generic
     PCH [plughw:0,1], version 4.4.0-66-generic
     PCH [plughw:0,3], version 4.4.0-66-generic
     PCH [plughw:0,7], version 4.4.0-66-generic
     Port PCH [hw:0], version 4.4.0-66-generic

  For each mixer, AudioSystem.getMixer(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()[x])
   Results:
      org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioMixer@685f4c2e
      com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@7a07c5b4
      com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@5ce65a89
      com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@1de0aca6
      com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@443b7951
      com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@45283ce2
      com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer@4d76f3f8
```

Comment: Your description is a little confusing. Are you hearing them at the same time or not? Which do you want?

Comment: I thought Java Sound was already multi threaded

Comment: Hi!  I have just updated the description to be a bit clearer.  I was unsure if it was or not so I just created new threads.  I'm only hearing one at a time, I want to hear both at the same time.

Comment: Based on my limited testing, `finish` should be declared `volatile`, but, a `CountDownLatch` would actually be a better mechanism for monitoring when the two threads complete

Comment: Declared finish as volatile but still only runs one.   I believe it could also be a problem with     `while( !s1.finished || !s2.finished)`

Comment: Call `getMixerInfo()` on AudioSystem and check the mixers returned by your system. Mixers have a maximum number of lines that can be open simultaneously, and depending on which one is used you might get one that only supports playback of a single clip at a time. You might have to specify a mixer or go through the list and find a suitable one (format supported and more than one line supported).

Comment: To be more precise, getMixerInfo will return an array of `Mixer.Info` instances but you can get the corresponding Mixer for each using getMixer with each in AudioSystem. That instance will tell you how many lines are supported. The Mixer.Info provides vendor, name and version info.

Comment: G_H, I have updated my question to show the results of these commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imports:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
```

Run method:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("NameOfFile.wav"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); // There are several different amounts of time you can loop it, so you can change this if you want, or you can just use clip.stop() whenever you want.
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you use this and piece of code over multiple threads, it should work. If I am correct in assuming that you are initiating this piece of code twice, once for each thread, then this should work. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
  public void run() {
    try {
        File file = new File(filename);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, audioInputStream.getFormat());
        Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); // There are several different amounts of time you can loop it, so you can change this if you want, or you can just use clip.stop() whenever you want.
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finished = true;
}
```

Also, if you're running Ubuntu like myself you need to [remove OpenJDK/OpenJRE and set SunJDK/SunJRE as Default.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21131/how-to-correctly-remove-openjdk-openjre-and-set-sunjdk-sunjre-as-default)